# Imagemaps and Statelessness - is it possible?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, rest

I created a clickable tag cloud generator. The tool generates a nice image which is the actual tag cloud, and also to make it clickable and hover-able (interactive), the tool (essentially a method in a class) also returns some HTML.

Since the image and HTML are both generated in the same action method, in my MVC project, I am wondering whether to return a ViewResult (with HTML) or an FileResult (with the Image). I do not want to use the session, and i have `<sessionState mode="OFF">` in my App.

Right now, I have a partial solution, where I save the image to the filesystem and send back the HTML ViewResult with the `<img>` tag in it pointing to the saved image. This obviously will not work with concurrent users (each user may overwrite the file, and interfere with each other)

Essentially what is the best way to send the image and HTML to the browser, without using server-side session? And without using an elaborate filesystem based store for the images?
I'm aware of the `<img src="data: .. " />` and since it does not work IE7 and less, and since the image is quite big, its not an option.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there anything against adding a custom HTTP Header while sending back the image response, which contains the HTML? I can then use jQuery to fetch the image and the imagemap html from the response's http header..

Answer (score 1):

Your image must be identifiable in some unique way. Perhaps a time stamp of when the tag cloud was changed? Or a hash of the tags in that cloud?

Put your image  and image map  into storage.

Mike Brown

Comment: It looks like something that will work, with a hash composed out of tags & weights associated with the tags, or a timestamp. When you say storage do you mean a filesystem folder?

Comment: To make my intent clearer, I was looking for some way to send the image and the imagemap html as parts of the same response stream.